# UL elements being overflow outside of parent container

Tags: html, css

I am having a bit of trouble getting my `li` elements to stay within the parent container. They continue to go off the right side of the page for some reason.

`Overflow: Auto` seems to fix the problem, but the issue with that is that it cuts off the border and doesn't allow me to scale the `li` elements properly (I want to have them be about 30% width of the parent container eventually).

Can anyone explain why this is happening or suggest an alternative solution?

Here is my code:
https://repl.it/KZXi/0

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Relevant code belongs directly into your question, so please edit it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://repl.it/KZXi/2
The problem is the by the default the box-sizing property excludes the padding, that is why your li element contain more than 100% of its parent please read https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp
To solve just add..

```
.answerBox {
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /*margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;*/
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much! One question though, I thought I had accounted for this when I had set the box-sizing on the entire body to be set to border-box at the top of the css file. Is there a certain reason why setting it to body does not apply it to everything?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the box-sizing on your list elements to include padding.

```
box-sizing:border-box
```

At the moment your list elements are 100% width + padding-left:40px and padding-right:40px so they overflow the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS to your `li`:

```
li.answerBox {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 4%;            /* <---- */
  width: 91%;             /* <---- */
  height: 70px;
```

The problem is, when you give padding and border, the content overflows.